# Key error at 'data' in Django class based view

Tags: python, django

I am getting key error at data!Means data doesnt exist but i am accessing it, but i have given condition for that,if data is None then execute this otherwise pass, still its raising error. Or am i handling the error path wrongly? How should i handle this error properly? Please be correcting me.

```
class ApiListView(TemplateView):
        def get(self, request):
            list_view = GetList().get_list_data()
            movie_list= list_view.json()
            cart_list_view = GetCartList().get_list_data(request).json()
            print(request.user)
            print(cart_list_view['data'])


            total = 0
            l = []
            if cart_list_view['data'] is not None:
                for object in cart_list_view['data']:
                    obj = object['cart_id']
                    l.append(obj)
                    total = len(l)
            else:
                pass

            if self.request.session.session_key:
                #session = self.request.session_key
                context = {
                    'movie_list':movie_list,
                    'home_status':'Show LoggedIn Page',
                    'total_items': total,

                           }
                return render(request,'content-list.html' , context)
            else:
                context = {'movie_list':movie_list}
                return render(request, 'content-list.html', context)
```

TRACEBACK ERROR

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myuser']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\customuser\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\customuser\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\customuser\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\customuser\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\customuser\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\customuser\venv\signup\myuser\views.py" in get
  24.         print(cart_list_view['data'])

Exception Type: KeyError at /
Exception Value: 'data'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback shows that the error is on the line `print(cart_list_view['data'])`. That is *before* you check whether it is `None` or not.

Note that `if cart_list_view['data'] is not None` will give an error if the `data` key is missing. To check that, you could do:

```
if 'data' in cart_list_view:  # check whether key is in data
```

or

```
if cart_list_view.get('data'):  # check that 'data' is in dictionary and is truthy
```

Answer (score 2):

no this is not how you check if a key exists in a dict or not change your code to either `cart_list_view.get('data')` this will return you none if the key doesn't exist or you can use something  like `if 'data' in cart_list_view`

hope that helps